# Extending enum attributes

Tags: java, enums

I have a simple enum like this

```
public enum TypeId {
    Unknown(0),
    I1(1),
    I2(2),
    I4(3),
    I8(4),
    Ui1(5),
    Ui2(6),
    Ui4(7) 
    // ...
    ;
    private final int ID;
    private TypeID (int id) { ID = id; }
    public int getID () { return ID;  }
    public static TypeID getTypeID(int id) { ... }
};
```

And a more complicated one, containing more data, but covering the same elements related via the same id number.

```
public enum DataType {
    T_Null(0, "NULL", Types.NULL, 0, 0),
    T_Int8(1, "TINYINT", Types.TINYINT, 1, 4), 
    T_Int16(2, "SMALLINT", Types.SMALLINT, 2, 6), 
    T_Int32(3, "INTEGER", Types.INTEGER, 4, 11),
    T_Int64(4, "BIGINT", Types.BIGINT, 8, 20), 
    T_UInt8(5, "BYTE", Types.TINYINT, 1, 3), // 0 -> 255
    T_UInt16(6, "USHORT", Types.SMALLINT, 2, 5), // 0 -> 65535
    T_UInt32(7, "UINT", Types.INTEGER, 4, 10) // 0 -> 4294967295  
    // ...
    ; 
    private final int typeCode, sqlTypeCode, binSize, dispSize;
    private String typeName;

    private DataType(int typeCode, String typeName, int sqlTypeCode, int binSize, int dispSize) {
      this.typeCode = TypeCode;
      this.typeName = TypeName;
      this.sqlTypeCode = sqlTypeCode;
      this.binSize = binSize;
      this.dispSize = dispSize;
    }
    public String getName() { return typeName; }
    // other getters 
};
```

Now the first enum is given, and the second one is a kind of extension.
Can this be implemented using **extends** or similar?

I want to achieve that the link via the same (ID == typeCode) is maintained / checked automatically.

One idea is to replace the int typeCode by a TypeId contained Element.

Questions:

- Is this a good/bad idea ?
- Are there better approaches to marry these two classes ?
- Is it good to define the "extension" as an enum at all? (or rather a static final array ?)

Comment: Why do you need a separate `TypeId`?

Comment: @Jorn: That's what I got already from an existing package. But I need those other attributes as well so I want to "extend" it somehow. Up to now, I simply invented my own enum in parallel, but that seems not optimal to me...

Comment: Ah ok, so you're trying to work with api that requires a `TypeId`?

Comment: Yes, and it also returns  TypeID values. I then call getID() and look up the number in my own enum. ( Not optimal, I fear )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not able to *extend* an enum, however *composition* achieves a similar result.

```
public enum DataType {
    T_Null(TypeId.Unknown, "NULL", Types.NULL, 0, 0),
    T_Int8(TypeId.I1, "TINYINT", Types.TINYINT, 1, 4), 
    T_Int16(TypeId.I2, "SMALLINT", Types.SMALLINT, 2, 6), 
    T_Int32(TypeId.I4, "INTEGER", Types.INTEGER, 4, 11),
    T_Int64(TypeId.I8, "BIGINT", Types.BIGINT, 8, 20), 
    T_UInt8(TypeId.Ui1, "BYTE", Types.TINYINT, 1, 3), // 0 -> 255
    T_UInt16(TypeId.Ui2, "USHORT", Types.SMALLINT, 2, 5), // 0 -> 65535
    T_UInt32(TypeId.Ui4, "UINT", Types.INTEGER, 4, 10) // 0 -> 4294967295  
    ; 
    private final TypeId typeId;
    private final int sqlTypeCode, binSize, dispSize;
    private final String typeName;

    private DataType(TypeId typeId, String typeName, int sqlTypeCode, int binSize, int dispSize) {
      this.typeId = typeId;
      this.typeName = typeName;
      this.sqlTypeCode = sqlTypeCode;
      this.binSize = binSize;
      this.dispSize = dispSize;
    }
    public String getName() { return typeName; }
    // other getters 

    public static DataType ofType(TypeId typeId) {
        for (DataType dt : values())
            if (dt.typeId == typeId)
                return dt;
        return T_Null;
    }

};
```

Presumably you are motivated to use an existing API more naturally.  If the existing apis are:

```
public TypeId someApi(int i) {  ....  }

public void myApi(DataType dt) { ... you prefer to use DataType ... }
```

Then you now have a natural way to invoke myApi as follows:

```
myApi(DataType.ofType(someApi(5)));
```

Answer (score 1):

The simplest approach would be to make both enums implement an `interface`. Obviously you still don't have the full safety checks and uniqueness becomes your problem but it is one solution.

```
public interface HasId {
    int getID ();
}

public enum TypeID implements HasId{
    Unknown(0),
    I1(1),
    I2(2),
    I4(3),
    I8(4),
    Ui1(5),
    Ui2(6),
    Ui4(7)
    ;
    private final int ID;
    private TypeID (int id) { ID = id; }
    @Override
    public int getID () { return ID;  }
};

public enum DataType implements HasId{
    T_Null(0, "NULL", Types.NULL, 0, 0),
    T_Int8(1, "TINYINT", Types.TINYINT, 1, 4),
    T_Int16(2, "SMALLINT", Types.SMALLINT, 2, 6),
    T_Int32(3, "INTEGER", Types.INTEGER, 4, 11),
    T_Int64(4, "BIGINT", Types.BIGINT, 8, 20),
    T_UInt8(5, "BYTE", Types.TINYINT, 1, 3), // 0 -> 255
    T_UInt16(6, "USHORT", Types.SMALLINT, 2, 5), // 0 -> 65535
    T_UInt32(7, "UINT", Types.INTEGER, 4, 10) // 0 -> 4294967295  
    // ...
    ;
    private final int typeCode, sqlTypeCode, binSize, dispSize;
    private String typeName;

    private DataType(int typeCode, String typeName, int sqlTypeCode, int binSize, int dispSize) {
        this.typeCode = typeCode;
        this.typeName = typeName;
        this.sqlTypeCode = sqlTypeCode;
        this.binSize = binSize;
        this.dispSize = dispSize;
    }
    public String getName() { return typeName; }
    // other getters
    @Override
    public int getID () { return typeCode;  }
};
```

I would probably use a `TypeId` instead of `int` for the `typeCode` of your `DataType` enum.

Comment: Perhaps a silly question: What's the benefit to have the     @Override
with the two  public int getID () { return ID / typeCode;  }  methods?   But thanks for confirming to use a TypeId instead of int typeCode.

Comment: @datafiddler - That is to confirm that the override of the interface method is deliberate.

Comment: Sure. (I asked the wrong question, sorry). I rather do not see the real benefit of this interface. Just to be sure both enums have a method called int getID(); Not sure if I can ever use an HasId object to call that method. And for dealing with DataType or TypeID elements I would not really mind if one of them has a getID() method and the other one had e.g. a getTypeCode() method. Of course naming them both getID() is convenient, but is that all, the interface stuff is about?

Answer (score 1):

In fact the `ID` (resp. `typeCode`) is nothing more than an explicit equivalent of the implicit `ordinal()` of the enum.

That means that you can easily ensure that you have the same number of values in both enums. If they are different that means that the enums are not coherent. You could simply add a static bloc in another class that you are sure to load (for example the one containing `main` if it is relevant):

```
static {
    if (DataType.values().length != TypeID.values().length) {
        throw new Error("Different lengths");
    }
}
```

You could additionally if you want to keep the explicit ID ensure that it is equal to the ordinal:

```
enum TypeID {
    ...
    private TypeID (int id) {
        ID = id;
        if (id != ordinal()) throw new Error("ID out of sequence");
    }
}
```

That way you can make sure that both enums have coherent ids.

Comment: Nice idea, thanks. I think, I combine the static length check with adding the TypeID as an attribute to  enum DataType ( instead of same int ID )

That way, the api might add more IDs with gaps later. And it would require to keep my enum DataType in sync, adding the other attributes properly.